# Mysql how to select base on priority

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

How to achieve this by joins and group by or any other alternative

Tab 1:

```
id | data  
1  | aaa  
2  | bbb  
3  | ccc
```

tab 2:

```
id  | tab1ID | status  
101 | 1      | Y  
102 | 2      | Y  
103 | 1      | X  
104 | 2      | X  
105 | 3      | X  
106 | 1      | Z  
107 | 2      | Z
```

required output:

```
id | data | status  
1 | aaa |  Z  
2 | bbb |  Z  
3 | ccc |  X
```

Record with the highest priority status has to come up in the result `Z > Y > X`

I want to avoid creating a separate table to store the priority order

Edit 1: change in sample data

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent status, then one method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.status
        from tab2 t2
        where t2.tab1id = t1.id
        order by t2.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as status
from tab1 t1;
```

EDIT:

If you just want the highest status, use `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select t1.*, max(t2.status)
from tab1 t1 left join
     tab2 t2
     on t2.tab1id = t1.id
group by t1.id;
```

Note:  The use of `select t1.*` is permitted and even supported by the ANSI standard, assuming that `t1.id` is unique (a reasonable assumption).

Comment: thanks @Gordon highest priority order may come up. i have change the sample data can you suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, give a row number to the second table based on the columns `tablID` and the priority of `status`. Then join it with the first table to get the the columns `id` and `data` and select only the rows having row number is 1.

**Query**

```
select t1.`id`, t1.`data`, t2.`status` 
from `tab1` t1
left join(
  select `id`, `tab1ID`, `status`,
  (
    case `tab1ID` when @curA 
    then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
    else @curRow := 1 and @curA := `tab1ID` end 
  ) as rn 
  from `tab2`,
  (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
  order by `tab1ID`, case `status` when 'Z' then 1 
                     when 'Y' then 2 when 'X' then 3 else 4 end
)t2
on t1.`id` = t2.`tab1ID`
where t2.rn = 1;
```

**[`SQL Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da438f/1)**